# How to override Sitecore RichText field

Tags: sitecore, richtext

I want to create a custom field for my Sitecore project that inherits from a Sitecore Rich Text field (Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentEditor.RichText).  The field will be a read-only field and I want my code to run when the field is loaded/displayed and I need to override the value.  What I am seeing is that my code does run.  However when I view the content item in Sitecore nothing is displayed in the Rich Text field.  If I click the Show Editor button or the Edit HTML button to view the HTML, my HTML content is there.  And if I then close the little Sitecore pop-up and go back to the content item I can now see my HTML.  The problem is that it doesn't display the first time I come to the screen.  I get the feeling that I am not overriding the correct method of the base control.  Here is my code

```
public class MyCustomField : Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentEditor.RichText
{
  protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
  {
    ...insert custom code here to build HTML string...
    base.Value = _myHTML;
    base.OnLoad(e);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.  I was overriding the wrong method.  Once I switched it to override the OnPreRender method it worked fine.  Code should look like this:

```
public class MyCustomField : Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentEditor.RichText
{
  protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
  {
    ...insert custom code here to build HTML string...
    this.Value = _myHTML;
    base.OnPreRender(e);
  }
}
```